# Let $n>1$ and $g_1,...,g_{n-1}$ be $C^2$ scalar fields over $\mathbb R^n$ , then for any scalar field $f$ , is $\det J(f,g_1,...,g_{n-1})=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let $n>1$ and $g_i:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ be  scalar field for each $1\le i\le n-1$ such that all second order partial derivatives of each $g_i$ exist and are continuous  ( i.e. each $g_i$ is $C^2$) , then is it true that for any scalar field $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ , the determinant of the Jacobian of the function $F:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$, defined as $F:=(f,g_1,...,g_{n-1})$ , is $0$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply take $g_i (x)=x_i$  and $f(x)=x_n$ to get a counterexample. Here, $x =(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in \Bbb{R}^n$.

Comment: What do you mean by $f(x)=x_n$ ?

Comment: @SaunDev: I edited my answer to make it more clear.